# How to Redirect to an MVC web app controller from azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using azure logic app which consumes a web API via a connector and based on some condition, I want to send some data to a controller of my web application.

any ideas how this can be done ?

Comment: What's your exact question? How to send the data, or how to call the specific action on the controller? What kind of action are you trying to call (GET, POST) and what type of data do you need to send? 'Cause those things will have an impact on how to solve this.

Comment: what I want is to redirect to a particular controller and send json data (post). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say don't over think this too much.   It's a pretty basic process.

1. Get the response form your API.
2. Extract the values you need to test for the condition
3. Test the values in a Condition Action
4. Call the end points based on each Condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTTP action in your Logic App to send data to a specific endpoint:

[image: Screenshot of HTTP action]

As you can see you're also able to add dynamic content to the body you would like to send.

For more information, check [Get started with the HTTP action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http).